# Excel add-in Not Functioning Properly

Tags: vba, excel, macros, add-in, excel-addins

I am attempting to create an excel add-in that would allow me to add a prefix to all entries in a column.

I think I figured out some code to do this, but unfortunately I keep receiving an error message that "The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled. I've tried all the recommended disabling of security settings.

I hope to be able to simply select text, use the add-on, and have a prefix added to every column. Cheers and thanks so much for looking into this!

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()



On Error Resume Next 'Just in case

'Delete any existing menu item that may have been left.

Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Super Code").Delete

'Add the new menu item and Set a CommandBarButton Variable to it

Set cControl = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add

'Work with the Variable

    With cControl

        .Caption = "Super Code"

        .Style = msoButtonCaption

        .OnAction = "MyGreatMacro"

        'Macro stored in a Standard Module

    End With



On Error GoTo 0


End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_AddinUninstall()



On Error Resume Next 'In case it has already gone.

Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Super Code").Delete

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Private Sub AddTextOnLeft()
'Updateby20131128
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim addStr As String
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
addStr = Application.InputBox("Add text", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
Rng.Value = addStr & Rng.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the OnAction you have assigned 'MyGreatMacro' instead of 'AddTextOnLeft'

it should be

```
.OnAction = "AddTextOnLeft"
```

and not

```
.OnAction = "MyGreatMacro"
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting! changed that section but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: This is because you will be having your code in a private module [eg : ThisWorkbook or Sheet1(Sheet1) ]. Therefore it cannot find the AddTextOnLeft routine .So insert the same code in a public module by creating a new module. Right click on your project select Insert->Module and insert it there and it will work

Comment: I tried opening a new excel spreadsheet, going into developer mode, and adding on the new code to a new module. I then saved the excel file as a .xlam. I added the ad-in under the options -> Add-Ins -> Manage, but now the add-in doesn't show up at all under the add-ins tab. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As per your code you need to run Workbook_AddinInstall() for the button to appear on the ribbon. Just adding the add-in file won't do. If you want it to appear on the ribbon on excel start up then you need to edit the .xlam file in Custom UI Editor. To know how to set it visit http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm